# How to add the filename as a new column in the database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I use the RailsCast episode #396 Importing CSV and Excel and this works very well.

Now I want to add a new column (filename) with the filename in each line.
I am aware that I need to create a new table with an new migrate.

system.rb:

```
class System < ActiveRecord::Base


def self.import(file)
  spreadsheet = open_spreadsheet(file)
  header = spreadsheet.row(1)
  (2..spreadsheet.last_row).each do |i|
    row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]

    system = find_by_id(row["id"]) || new
    system.attributes = row.to_hash.slice(*System.attribute_names())
    system.save!
  end
end

def self.open_spreadsheet(file)
  case File.extname(file.original_filename)
  when ".csv" then Roo::Csv.new(file.path.encode!("UTF-8", "Cp437"), csv_options: {col_sep: "\;"})             #, csv_options: {encoding: Encoding::ISO_8859_1})
 # when ".xls" then Excel.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
 # when ".xlsx" then Excelx.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
  else raise "Unknown file type: #{file.original_filename}"
  end
end


end
```

controller.rb:

```
class SystemsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_system, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, ]

  # GET /systems
  # GET /systems.json
  def index
    @systems = System.all
    db = SQLite3::Database.new './db/development.sqlite3' 
    @datens = db.execute 'SELECT ID1, ID2 FROM systems'
  end



def import
  System.import(params[:file])
  redirect_to root_url, notice: "yeah"
end
```

index.html.erb:

```
<%= form_tag import_systems_path, multipart: true do %>
  <%= file_field_tag :file %>
  <%=  %>
  <%= submit_tag "read" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: What is your ultimate goal that you're trying to accomplish which lead you to this type of solution?

Comment: I want to load different customer data in this table. I wanted to use the file name to assign the data.

Comment: but now I'm thoughtful. Is it better to create for every customer a new Table?

Answer (score 0):

```
def self.import(file)
  file_name = File.basename(file)
  row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose].merge({:file_name => file_name})
OR
  row.to_hash.slice(*System.attribute_names()).merge({:file_name => file_name})
end
```

add these  lines in self.import(file), assuming you had run a migration and added file_name field.

Comment: Thank' s Atul, but now I get an TypeError `no implicit conversion of ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile into String` at this line `file_name = File.basename(file)`

Comment: try using file_name = file.original_filename